# Google Sheets & Analytics API Formatting Cells

Tags: google-sheets

I am pulling in my Google analytics data per landing page and have pulled in the average time on page. When I pulled in, it shows as for example - `181.0740741` in the cell, it should show as `00:03:01` as shown in Analytics.

Does anyone know what format can I use?

Also when trying to format dates pulled through e.g. `201501`, I am getting September 8th, when it should be January 2015.

Answer (score 0):

The first is counting seconds past midnight (3 minutes each of 60 seconds = 180), the second days since 1900. By the looks of it you will need to do some calculations. For time dividing by the number of seconds in a day should be adequate, with suitable formatting. Say:

```
=A1/86400
```

For date you will need to separate the year from the month number and then concatenate the results in the reverse order. Say:

```
 =text(month(right(A1,2)),"mmmm")&" "&left(A1,4)
```

where I have included some formatting to display the `01` as `January`.